Creating User-defined Function
I'm working with the following table:
Employees_2 (
    EmpID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Department VARCHAR(50),
    Salary DECIMAL(8,2),
    DateOfJoining DATE
);

I need to create a user-defined function to determine if an employee is a 'Senior' (more than 3 years with the company) or 'Junior'. Then, list all employees with this designation.
So far I've come up with the following code:
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION DESIGNATION(DateOfJoining DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN DESIGNATION = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DateOfJoining) / 365.25);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

How can I assign 'Senior' & 'Junior'?

You seem to be asking for 2 different outcomes please clarify by providing sample data and desired outcomes as text.

In MySQL you'd use not DATEDIFF(... but TIMESTAMPDIF(YEAR, ...

note that CURDATE() is the date in the timezone of your connection.  I prefer being explicit about what date you mean, e.g. DATE(CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP,'+00:00','Asia/Kolkata')).  Akina is correct, use TIMESTAMPDIFF for this, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DateOfJoining, DATE(CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP,'+00:00','Asia/Kolkata')))

but what does more than 3 years with the company mean?  4 years or more?  or 3 years and 1 day or more?

This question is part of an assignment where they've specifically asked for a UDF, followed by SELECT (2 diff outcomes). Since the Joining Date column is in DATE format, I went with DATEDIFF (TIMESTAMPDIFF didn't occur to me).

=3, Senior, ELSE Junior

I tried with an IF statement, and it worked. Thanks a lot for all y'all support. I'm a beginner in this, so I appreciate all the help I can get.. :D

note that this is not DETERMINISTIC, since it depends on the current date, unless you change to to take a current date parameter

Why create a function? Just do with SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,date1,date2)
SELECT *, IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DateOfJoining, NOW()) >= 3,'senior','junior') label FROM Employees_2


Thanks a lot for the code, it works :). This is part of an assignment I'm doing where they've specifically asked me to create a UDF and SELECT * FROM table.

So to determine whether an Employee is 'Senior' or 'Junior' from a user-defined function based on DateOfJoining passed, use the below function definition snippet:
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION DESIGNATION(DateOfJoining DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN (CASE
            WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DateOfJoining) / 365.25) >= 3 THEN 'Senior'
            ELSE 'Junior'
        END);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

Then write your select query to select employees with particular designations. For selecting all 'Senior' designation employees you will do something like this:
SELECT e2.*
FROM Employees_2 e2
WHERE DESIGNATION(e2.DateOfJoining) = 'Senior';

So to conclude, you won't be able to select the second outcome from a user-defined function. You must write a select query as shown above or define a stored procedure to include both the requirements.
Hope this helps!

Hey @robin.e.rr Thanks a lot for the code. I tried and it worked. I also tried with same with an IF statement (similar to Excel) and that worked too.
I'm a beginner, so appreciate the help. :D

glad to be of help
